# error when calling a copy constructor that have a function as actual parameter

Tags: c++

i have an error massage says that there is no constructor matches the argument list but when i remove the user difined copy constructor the error is fixed please help me find the error

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
#include<cctype>
#include<iomanip>
#include<climits>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<numeric>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
#include<set>
#include<unordered_set>
#include<map>
#include<stack>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
class a
{
public :
    a(a& x)
    {
        cout << 1 << endl;
    }
    a() {}
};
a f()
{
    a aa;
    return aa;
}
int main(void)
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0), cin.tie(0), cout.tie(0);
    a aa(f());



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot bind a prvalue(such as the temporary object returned by `f`) to a reference to non-const. A copy constructor should take a reference to const...

Comment: `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0), cin.tie(0), cout.tie(0);` -- This is definitely a copy-and-paste from one of those competition websites.  Very few, if any actual C++ programmers would waste time typing this in, let alone "remembering to do this" -- it is obscure as a 5 leaf clover.  Second, the only header needed is `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Side note: https://godbolt.org/z/bKzbz4MWW Note the absence of output in the c++17 build. Copy elision in action. You could have gotten away with this with a newer compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Take the reference as `const`.

```
a(const a& x)
{
    cout << 1 << endl;
}
```

A temporary (like the return value of a function) can be bound to a `const&` of the appropriate type but cannot be bound to a non-const lvalue reference, since it has no actual name to speak of.

Comment: but it wont print 1 when the value is returned also when copying in the main function

Comment: Returns from functions are subject to [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), so your copy constructor won't always be called.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `f()` is a temporary and an rvalue. Basically, it cannot be bind to `a&` which is a reference to an lvalue (a "normal" object with a certain lifetime, to oversimplify).

In order to initialize your object with `f()`, you have two solutions:

change to:

```cpp
a(const a& x)
```

as you can bind a temporary to a reference to const.

or:

```cpp
a(a&& x)
```

as it is the correct signature for binding an rvalue.

The later form is called a [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor), while the first one is the correct signature for a copy constructor.

Comment: Minor point: both `a(const a&)` and `a(a&)` are valid signatures for a copy constructor (as well as `a(volatile a&)` and `a(const volatile a&)`). `a(a&)` isn’t common, but it’s not technically incorrect. +1.